# Undocumented `*` in PostgreSQL tsquery?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I was playing with tsquery and found that I can use `*` alone, (not as in foo:*), and it is accepted, but I have no idea of the behavior of this operator or if it is safe to use it

Here is an example

```
SELECT *, ts_rank_cd(x, query) AS rank
FROM to_tsquery('cat & *') query,
    (VALUES 
      (to_tsvector('cat say meow')),
      (to_tsvector('dog say woof'))) as t(x)
WHERE query @@ t.x
```

Here is a dbfidle with it https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/9036

It returns

```
| query | x                        | rank |
| ----- | ------------------------ | ---- |
| 'cat' | 'cat':1 'meow':3 'say':2 | 0.1  |
```

If I try it alone like `to_tsquery('*')`, it returns 0 rows. Does anybody know the behavior of this operator, or if is documented anywhere?

The documentation pages I checked were these:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-textsearch.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html

---

Update

I think it is recognized as a punctuation, because `?` or `.` works in the same way, the pertinent question is what punctuation matches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` is ignored:

```
SELECT to_tsquery('cat & *');

 to_tsquery 
════════════
 'cat'
(1 row)
```

So it is safe to use, but pointless.

`*` is nothing special here: the same happens with all characters that are not letters. They are simply ignored in full-text search.

Comment: Is, this is the same for . ? so I think it is treating it as punctuation, but I couldn't find a documentation of this behavior

Comment: I'm asking because I want to use it in production, but as I do not know the documentation I don't know the caveates that are waiting for me in the future if I depend on this behavior

Comment: I answered the question, right.

Comment: Fair enough, I accepted

Comment: But I'm still wondering what feature is behind this 

Comment: Don't suspect special features behind each corner. I have added an explanation.

Comment: Oh I didn't now that, THANKS!